# RMarkdown collapsible panel

Tags: r, r-markdown

As I am preparing tutorials for students, I need a way to hide content in collapsible panels which can be revealed by clicking on a button. I have got this to work using the code below. The RMarkdown file looks like this:

````
---
title: Collapsible Panel
output:
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
    highlight: tango
---

<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
    Click For Answer
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
  <div class="card card-body">

  ```{r}
  hist(1:10)
  ```

  </div>
</div>
````

And it looks like this when rendered:

[image]

This works! I can also control if the **code** and/or **results** must be shown by controlling the chunk options.

But, this is not optimal because the code is messy and ugly with all the raw html. Copy-pasting this multiple times is not ideal. The ID used `collapseExample1` needs to be unique every time this code block is used.

Is there some way to package this block into a reusable unit like a function or something? I am thinking something like an R function, where I can pass in code to be evaluated (or code that don't need to be evaluated), chunk options (`eval`, `echo`, `results`, etc..) and state of the panel (open/closed).

`collapsible_panel(code=NULL,echo=TRUE,results="show",state="closed")`

I have many unclear questions at this point. Can I run R chunks inside R chunks? Maybe I need to use child Rmd files? Do I need to write some custom javascript?

Comment: Another way would be to have tabs, e.g. Question and Answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Another simple solution that would work *(but without buttons and styling)*.

````
```{r, eval=FALSE}
hist(1:10)
```

<details>
  <summary>Click for Answer</summary>
    ```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
    hist(1:10)
    ```
</details>
````

And here are the two states:

**Collapsed**
[image: collapsed]

**Expanded**
[image: expanded]

Comment: This works well for me.  Just in case it helps someone else, though, I was seeing raw HTML instead of the image for the histogram.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40734207/1714) explains why, and the fix

Comment: Great solution. And for those who (like me initially) wonder where the `details` and the `summary` tags are defined, see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp

Comment: @Hobo I see BOTH histogram and a bit a raw code (`::: {.cell} ::: {.cell-output-display}`). How exactly did you fix the issue?

Comment: @EmileZäkiev - I'm sorry, but I don't remember anything about this at all (I don't even remember hitting the problem).  Though what you've chatted looks like a different issue to whatever I was talking about - I assume by "raw html" I meant html tags like `<div>`, and those `{.cell}` values aren't html tags

Answer (score 19):

You can use [multiple tabs](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#tabbed-sections) (add `{.tabset}` after the header). It's very simple to generate them using `r-markdown` and they look almost the same as collapsible panel (of course you need to have more than one option).
Not to paste same code multiple times specify `code` argument in chunk options (`code = readLines("code.R")`). Or you can have only one panel for code and answer so you wouldn't need external document.

````
---
title: Collapsible Panel
output:
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
    highlight: tango
---

# Question 1 {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

## Question

How does uniform distribution look like?

## Code 

```{r, echo = TRUE, eval = FALSE, code = readLines("Q1.R")}
```

## Answer

```{r, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, code = readLines("Q1.R")}
```
````

Code file (`Q1.R`):

```
hist(1:10)
```

[image]

---

To not have any content and then show answer you can make first tab completely empty with:

````
# Question 1 {.tabset}

##  <span>&#8203;</span>

## Answer

```{r, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, code = readLines("Q1.R")}
```
````

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution! I hadn't thought of using tabs for this purpose. But, it's not possible to show/hide the code part by the user.

Comment: One solution is to use 3 tabs. First tab will have the question. Second can have the code and third, the result. Or two tabs with first tab as question and second tab as code+results.

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas, This is pretty good. But I would like to see if there is a better solution that doesn't use tabs. Tabs do not work well with printing the HTML to PDF for example.

Comment: @rmd There should be a way to make collapsible sections (for example your original code), my answer is just a *clean* (uses already implemented r-markdown options)  workaround.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Two slightly different methods are shown. Both approaches use only HTML and CSS. Here is the full working Rmd.

````
---
title: Accordion
output:
  html_document
---

## Method 1

This method uses button.

```{css,echo=FALSE}
button.btn.collapsed:before
{
    content:'+' ;
    display:block;
    width:15px;
}
button.btn:before
{
    content:'-' ;
    display:block;
    width:15px;
}
```

```{r,echo=FALSE,results='hide'}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(drop1=function(before, options, envir) {
    if (before) {
        paste(
            '<p>',
'<button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ce1">',
'</button>',
'</p>',
'<div class="collapse" id="ce1">',
'<div class="card card-body">',  sep = "\n")
    } else {
        paste("</div>", "</div>", sep = "\n")
    }
})
```



```{r,drop1=TRUE,results="markup"}
str(iris)
```

## Method 2

This method uses a link which behaves like a button.

```{css,echo=FALSE}
[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed .if-not-collapsed {
  display: none;
}
[data-toggle="collapse"]:not(.collapsed) .if-collapsed {
  display: none;
}
```

```{r,echo=FALSE,results='hide'}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(drop2=function(before, options, envir) {
    if (before) {
        paste(
            '<p>',
'<a class="btn btn-primary collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ce2">',
'<span class="if-collapsed">+</span>',
'<span class="if-not-collapsed">-</span>',
'</a>',
'</p>',
'<div class="collapse" id="ce2">',
'<div class="card card-body">',  sep = "\n")
    } else {
        paste("</div>", "</div>", sep = "\n")
    }
})
```

```{r,drop2=TRUE,results="markup"}
str(iris)
```
````

Executed R chunks can be hidden in collapsible containers (collapsed by default). The containers are defined in the R chunk options using a custom knitr hook (`drop1`/`drop2`). The collapsible states of the container is controlled using a button or a link (looks like a button). Custom CSS is used to change text on the button for collapsed/open states.

Comment: Unfortunately, both methods do not allow to have multiple collapsible content elements. With both versions, it is always un/collapsing the first cell's content.

Comment: Cool method, but doesn't work in the current markdown version 2.20

Comment: @Emile It works fine for me using **knitr 1.42** and **rmarkdown 2.20**. But it doesn't seem to work in quarto document. I haven't looked into why. @Holger If multiple copies are used in the same document, the `data-target` label must be unique. In real world use, I generate a random string based on current date-time.