# Adding cross reference in html in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, bookdown, cross-reference

I am working on a Rmarkdown book with the package bookdown. At some point, I am using a R chunk to create some HTML code (with the option "asis" in the chunk header). In that HTML, I would like to add a reference to a chunk in an other part of the book. Note that this part is created in a separated html file by pandoc.

The function generating the HTML works well and the HTML is rendered as expected, but the references added with @ref(chunkid) are not converted to links. They are just plain text in the HTML.

I tried to add the function `cat` to print the HTML code, but if I do so, the HTML is not rendered and is shown as plain text.

This is what I have currently:

````
```{r results = 'asis'}
"<h2>An html title</h2>
<div>\\@ref(titi22)</div>
"
```\
````

This will render the expected HTML when the book is knitted but the link in the div is not created. @ref(titi22) is written in the div.

On the real case, this is what I get
[image: The real case]

If I add cat:

````
```{r results = 'asis'}
cat("<h2>An html title</h2>
<div>\\@ref(titi22)</div>
")
```\
````

The HTML is not rendered nor the reference.

How can I render the reference and the HTML?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the bookdown:

```
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
```

---

... it works right:

```
<h2>An html title</h2>
<div> Here is my first table: \@ref(tab:tab1) <div>
```

Tab:

````
```{r tab1}

#any tab

```
````

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to switch from gitbook to html2 in the yml. It changes a lot the style of the document and does not solve the issue. The cross reference is not formatted when the HTML code is produced **inside** a R chunk with the parameter results = "asis". In your example, the HTML code is written directly in the markdown. Do you have another idea?

Comment: @jérémyGelb you should tell before, that you work in the gitbook. Which version of the bookdown do you have?

Comment: @jérémyGelb look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635579/bookdown-chapter-section-cross-referencing-not-working-gitbook

Comment: Thank you for the links, it helped me finding the real issue. I also posted the answer below.

Comment: @jérémyGelb good luck and "+1" ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem was.

The html code I am using was produced with the library `htmltools` and converted to text with the function `doRenderTags`. This function do a nice job but the indentation is no read as expected by pandoc (see here : [R markdown asis breaks valid html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730902/r-markdown-asis-breaks-valid-html-code)). So the solution was just to use the parameter `indent = FALSE` in `doRenderTags`. After that, the HTML code was not indented and rendered as expected by pandoc.